# Placeholder issues in Firefox only

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have an issue that I am trying to troubleshoot with regards to placeholder text in Firefox.

I am using the following method,

`.classname::-moz-placeholder {....}`

But it ignores it on input fields. It does however work with textareas?
Also I copied over the css and html into js fiddle and it works as expected in FF?

http://jsfiddle.net/h1rg5ooj/7/

But on my website it refuses to style the input placeholders on FF.

I have tried various things to try and get it to work including adding input.class etc still no joy.

Im guessing its something conflicting as it works in jsfiddle, just not sure where to look now.

Has anyone got any suggestions how to troubleshoot this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.contact-input` Has a fixed height and a high padding. Youre just hiding your content. I'm really not quite sure why it does work in jsFiddle. If you want to set the height for your text try using `line-height`

Comment: Thanks Alex. That was the problem. Cant believe I missed that.